# Using regex in Google Analytics to define a funnel

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm attempting to set up a funnel in GA based on the destination page being /m/thanks(.*) where there are multiple one-time-offer pages in between that add a additional parameters to the URI.

The desired goal is to measure a *Free signup*. The flow looks like this..

- **Destination Page:**
  `/m/thanks?id=3LKJE-a723a72bc96cba65&oto=no&oto=no`

*The `oto=no&oto=no` signify that the user has declined both OTO pages, and therefore results in a free lead*

- **Step 1: Landing page:** (literal URL)
- **Step 2: Signup Page:** (literal URL)
- **Step 3: OTO 1:** `/m/thanks?id=3LKJE-a723a72bc96cba65`

*The string after `?id=` is dynamically generated, but **does not contain** `&oto=no`*

- **Step 4: OTO 2:** `/m/thanks?id=3LKJE-a723a72bc96cba65&oto=no`

*Same id, but contains exactly one instance of `&oto=no`*

---

I'm not sure the best way to represent step 3 and 4 to make sure I am recording **only** those pages.

Comment: Never worked with GA and I'm not sure what flavor it supports. But generally if you add `(?!&oto=no)` at the end of your expression, it will match if there is no `&oto=no` following your expression.

Comment: If I do `/m/thanks(.*)(?!&oto=no)` and check it using [this regex checker](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#experiment), It still returns the results for `/m/thanks?id=3LKJE-a723a72bc96cba65&oto=no` Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: my bad, try `/m/thanks(.*?)(?!&oto=no)`. Note the added `?` which makes it ungreedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This regex will:

- validate the string does not have a `&oto=no` value
- captures the query string value for ID
- validates the string has `/m/thanks?`
- allow the querystring attributes to appear in any order

`^(?!.*?&oto=no)(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*))\/m\/thanks(?=[?])`

[image]

- `^` match the start of the string
- `(?!.*?&oto=no)` look ahead an validate we can't find a `oto=no` key value set
- `(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*))` look ahead and validate we have the `id` and capture the value
- `\/m\/thanks(?=[?])` ensure the string starts with /m/thanks?

## OR

This regex will:

- validate you have 2 instances of `oto=no` in the string
- capture the ID value
- validates the string has `/m/thanks?`
- allow the querystring attributes to appear in any order

`^(?=(?:.*?&oto=no){2})(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*))\/m\/thanks(?=[?])`

[image]

- `^` match the start of the string
- `(?=(?:.*?&oto=no){2})` validate that `oto=no` exists twice in the query string
- `(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*))` capture the `id` value
- `.*?(?=[?])` capture the string upto the first `?`

Comment: Thank you for the *awesome* answer, but being the noob I am, I still have a couple questions. In your first regex explanation, you mention `\/m\/thanks(?=[?])`, but don't make it part of the equation above. Do I need to include this anywhere? I'm also not exactly sure where to put the `/m/thanks?` in relation to the answer provided. Finally, when I ran `^(?!.*?&aoto=no)(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*)).*?(?=[?])` with this [regex checker](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#experiment) to this link `/m/thanks?id=3LKJE-a723a72bc96cba65&oto=no` it found a match despite the `&oto=no`.

Comment: I have an extra character in the expression `(?!.*?&aoto=no)`, the letter `a` should not be there. It was added so I could do testing. After removing that character it worked as expected in your regex checker and returned `no match`

Comment: Aha! yes that does work when I put only the regex as you list it, but I need to include the path for GA purposes. Simply preceding the regex with it like this `/m/thanks^(?!.*?&oto=no)(?=.*?[?&]id=([^&]*)).*?(?=[?])` does not work. How could I include it?

Comment: You're too quick for me :)  ... For your other question, I've updated the answer to show where to put the `/m/thanks` portion. In the original answer your sample text was it was a bit unclear to me how you wanted to handle that portion of the string so I only forced the regex to capture the entire url upto the first question mark.

Comment: Beautiful! I'll mark it as accepted as soon as I know GA accepts this flavor. Thank you again.

Comment: Worked perfectly in GA. Thanks again.